# Creating loggers for a windows service and a wcf service hosted by that windows service

Tags: nlog

I create a logger in my windows service and it works fine until that service creates/hosts a wcf service. When I create the logger in the wcf service, logging destined for the windows service log is actually logged to the wcf service log. Here's some code excerpts:

Windows Service:

```
enum LoggingListeningPorts
{
  MCMessageService = 8182,
  MCService = 8183,
  MCWCFService = 8184,
  MyCourtsAdmin = 8185,
  MyCourtsWeb = 8186,
  MCManager = 8187,
  MCSupport = 8188,
  MyCourts = 8189
}
```

First I start logging in the Windows Service to the file directly as the TCP Listeners haven't been initialized:

```
    private void startFileLogging()
{
  string location = "target";
  try
  {
    LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
    FileTarget target = new FileTarget();
    target.Layout = "${longdate} ${machineName} ${callsite} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";
    target.FileName = Path.Combine(dataDirectory, "MCService.log");
    target.KeepFileOpen = false;

    eventLog1.WriteEntry(string.Format("target.FileName [{0}]", target.FileName), EventLogEntryType.Information);

    LoggingRule normalRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, target);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(normalRule);       
    LogManager.Configuration = config;
    location = "Config";
    LogFactory fac = logger.Factory as LogFactory;
    fac.GlobalThreshold = loglevel;

    location = "Logging";
    //logger.Debug(string.Format("### NRMAP{0}_{1}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version));
    //logger.Debug(string.Format("### MCCommon_{0}", mccommonVersionNumber));
    logger.Debug("##########################################");
    logger.Debug(string.Format("########  MyCourts Service {0} ", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version).PadRight(42, '#'));
    logger.Debug("##########################################");

    //logger.Debug(string.Format("#### MyCourts Service {0} StartUp ", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version));
    logger.Debug(string.Format("Database directory [{0}]", dataDirectory));
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Trace, "Trace level is [{0}]", logger.IsTraceEnabled);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    eventLog1.WriteEntry(string.Format("MCService Service logging failed at location [{0}]: {1}", location, ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Warning);
  }
}
```

Then I start the wcf service:

```
    mcwcfServiceHost.Open();
    logger.Trace("MCWCFService opened.");
```

At this stage the logging for the Windows Service is working perfectly. I then execute the following method in my Windows Service which includes starting logging on the wcf service:

```
private void initializeMCWCFService()
{
  logger.Debug("Set DB Path in MCWCFService");
  int pauseTime = 2000;
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pauseTime);

  EndpointAddress basicHTTPendpoint = null;
  EndpointAddress serverTCPEndpoint = null;

  var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
  var findCriteria = FindCriteria.CreateMetadataExchangeEndpointCriteria(typeof(MCWCFService.MCManagementService));
  findCriteria.MaxResults = 1;
  var findResults = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);

  if (findResults.Endpoints.Count > 0)
  {
    var endpoints = MetadataResolver.Resolve(typeof(MCWCFService.MCManagementService), findResults.Endpoints[0].Address);
    if (endpoints.Count > 0)
    {
      foreach (var item in endpoints)
      {
        if (item.Address.Uri.Scheme == "net.tcp")
        {
          logger.Debug("Discovered NetTcpAddress [{0}]", item.Address);
          //serverTCPEndpoint = item.Address;
          IPAddress[] serverIPAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(item.Address.Uri.Host);
          foreach (var address in serverIPAddresses)
          {
            if (address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
              serverTCPEndpoint = item.Address;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (item.Address.Uri.Scheme == "http")
        {
          logger.Debug("Discovered basicHTTPAddress [{0}]", item.Address);
          basicHTTPendpoint = item.Address;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else
    logger.Debug("Discovery failed for MCWCFService");

  logger.Debug("MCWCFService TCPEndpoint = [{0}]", serverTCPEndpoint);
  mcWCFEndpointAddress = serverTCPEndpoint;


  string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
  IPAddress hostIPAddress = null;
  IPHostEntry host;
  host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
  //logger.Debug("Host = [{0}]", host);
  foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
  {
    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
      hostIPAddress = ip;
      logger.Debug("MCService Host [{0}] IP address = [{1}]", hostName, ip);
    }
  }

  ChannelFactory<MCWCFService.IMCManagementService> scf = null;
  string location = "";
  try
  {
    location = "create scf";
    scf = new ChannelFactory<MCWCFService.IMCManagementService>(
               new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None),
               serverTCPEndpoint); 

    location = "create channel";
    MCWCFService.IMCManagementService channel = scf.CreateChannel();
    location = "set db path";
    channel.SetMyCourtsDataDirectory(dataDirectory);
    location = "set hostIPaddress";
    channel.SetMCServiceIPAddress(hostIPAddress);
    location = "start logging";
    channel.StartLogging();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    logger.Fatal("Unable to complete setdb path in MCWCFService @ [{0}]: {1}", location, ex);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (scf != null && scf.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {
      if (scf.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
        scf.Close();
    }

  }

}
```

Here's the method to start the logging on the WCF Service:

```
public void StartLogging()
{
  try
  {
    LoggingConfiguration cfg = new LoggingConfiguration();

    NetworkTarget networkTarget = new NetworkTarget();
    networkTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${machineName} ${callsite} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";
    networkTarget.Address = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}", mcServiceIPAddress, (int)LoggingListeningPorts.MCWCFService);
    networkTarget.NewLine = false;
    networkTarget.KeepConnection = false;
    networkTarget.Name = "network1";

    LoggingRule networkRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, networkTarget);
    cfg.LoggingRules.Add(networkRule);

    LogManager.Configuration = cfg;

    mcmLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("MCManagementService");

    mcmLogger.Fatal("##########################################");
    mcmLogger.Trace(string.Format("########  MCWCFService {0} ",
      Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version).PadRight(42, '#'));
    mcmLogger.Fatal("##########################################");

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    eventlog.WriteEntry(string.Format("MCManagemntService error {0}", ex), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    //errorLogger.FatalException("Unable to start logging: ", ex);
  }
```

At this point, the loging from the Windows Service now gets logged to the WCF Service log.

The obvious solution is that I have mixed up the TCP Listening ports but I've checked that so many times I've got a headache.

I have also tried executing the following method on the Windows Service immediately after starting the logging on the WCF Service but it doesn't do anything...

```
private void startTCPLogging()
{
  logger.Debug("Starting TCP Logger");
  try
  {

    if (logger != null)
      logger = null;

    LoggingConfiguration cfg = new LoggingConfiguration();

    NetworkTarget networkTarget = new NetworkTarget();
    networkTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${machineName} ${callsite} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";
    networkTarget.Address = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}", mcWCFEndpointAddress, (int)LoggingListeningPorts.MCService);
    networkTarget.NewLine = false;
    networkTarget.KeepConnection = false;
    networkTarget.Name = "network1";

    LoggingRule networkRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, networkTarget);
    cfg.LoggingRules.Add(networkRule);

    LogManager.Configuration = cfg;
    logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Fatal("Logger switched to TCP Listener");

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //eventlog1.WriteEntry(string.Format("MCManagemntService error {0}", ex), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    //errorLogger.FatalException("Unable to start logging: ", ex);
  }
```

I need two separate logs and I can't see why they are combined into the WCF Service log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Windows Service and the WCF Service in the same process, then it could be due to the fact that you are resetting the `LogManager.Configuration` .

The instance of LogManager is available within your whole process. So, every time you set the configuration with a `new LoggingConfiguration()`, you loose the previous set configuration.

Try to set the LogManager.Configuration once, and from there just add or remove targets with methods like :

- LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName(..)
- LogManager.Configuration.RemoveTarget(..)
- LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(...)

or with the help of the property :

- LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets

Comment: Thank you -that makes sense as yes, the two classes "Windows Service" and "WCF Service" are indeed running within the same process.
To answer my question regarding achieving two separate logs I guess I could start the "WCF Service" in another process altogether but I will need to investigate further as to having achieving separate logs for different classes within the same process.